# VBA ms word set row in table as the row where the cursor is

Tags: vba, ms-word

this is what I have so far
but im struggling to SET oCurrentRow

```
Sub InsertRow()

Dim EventDate As String
Dim oTable As Table
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim oCurrentRow As Row
Dim oNewRow As Row

If Not Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
MsgBox "Can only run this within a table"
Exit Sub
End If


Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
Set oCurrentRow = Selection.Cells(1).RowIndex


oCurrentRow.Select
With Selection
.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
.InsertRowsAbove 1
End With
' go to inserted row and insert text

    End Sub
```

i am guessing that once I have inserted row above 
oCurrentRow will reference that newly inserted row
where i want to add some text in cell(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RowIndex returns a number, not a row, so it can't be used to set a row object. Change

```
Set oCurrentRow = Selection.Cells(1).RowIndex
```

To

```
Set oCurrentRow = oTable.Rows(Selection.Cells(1).RowIndex)
```

And you should be cooking with gas.